# calling previous data based on unique value and date in sql query

Tags: sql

anyone can help me to call name who's come in january, then they come again in february? for 1st data will give like this:
[1st data look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE48T.png)

and for the result hoping like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRrSh.png)

for the query i make like this

```
CREATE TABLE customerdata
(
    CustomerID CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY not null,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(255),
    CustomerGender VARCHAR(20),
)
drop table customerdata
SELECT * FROM customerdata
insert into customerdata(CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerGender)
values('C001','Alan','Male'),('C002','Lana','Female'),('C003','Aan','Male'),
('C004','Nala','Female'),('C005','Lala','Female'),('C006','Nana','Female'),
('C007','Anan','Male'),('C008','Citra','Female'),
('C009','Prabu','Male'),('C010','Fajar','Male');

CREATE TABLE TrTransaction(
TransID CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
CustomerID CHAR (7) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customerdata (CustomerID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
Product varchar(255),
Quantity INT,
TransDate date,
)
SELECT * FROM TrTransaction
insert into TrTransaction(TransID,CustomerID,Product,Quantity,TransDate)
values('TR001','C001','Milk A',5,'2021-01-01'),('TR002','C002','Milk A',2,'2021-01-03'),('TR003','C003','Milk B',3,'2021-01-08'),
('TR004','C004','Milk C',1,'2021-01-16'),('TR005','C005','Milk C',2,'2021-01-19'),('TR006','C006','Milk A',4,'2021-01-24'),
('TR007','C007','Milk B',2,'2021-01-28'),('TR008','C001','Milk C',3,'2021-02-02'),('TR009','C002','Milk D',4,'2021-02-02'),
('TR010','C004','Milk A',2,'2021-02-08'),('TR011','C005','Milk A',5,'2021-02-13'),('TR012','C008','Milk B',2,'2021-02-19'),
('TR013','C009','Milk C',3,'2021-02-21'),('TR014','C010','Milk D',1,'2021-02-25');
```

because I want calling data in february by name who listed in january.

Sorry, I don't have right a query to enter data into the table, because I'm confused whether one of the columns should be made unique or not. so it's ok if you want modif my create table. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` operator to find customers *"who come in january, then they come again in february"*, then join this with "customerdata" table to get their names. Try the following:

```
SELECT A.TransDate, B.CustomerName, A.Product, A.Quantity
  FROM
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM TrTransaction T
    WHERE MONTH(T.TransDate)=2 AND YEAR(T.TransDate)=2021
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TrTransaction D WHERE D.CustomerID=T.CustomerID 
              AND MONTH(D.TransDate)=1 AND YEAR(D.TransDate)=2021)
  ) A
JOIN customerdata B
ON A.CustomerID=B.CustomerID
ORDER BY A.CustomerID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2VzeI327) on SQL Server.